# Index-Match Formula Issue Across Table

Tags: excel, match

Summary

- I want to be able to copy over the index-match formula so that it fills in the rest of the table
- when I do so now, I get the #ref error message

Have tried

- Different combinations of column, row settings within formula but I get the #spill error

Current Formula I'm using

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$9994,MATCH($F2,$B$2:$B$9994,0),MATCH(G$1,$C$2:$C$9994,0))
```

Image of excel sheet

[image]

Comment: the third criterion of INDEX is the COLUMN and not another ROW criterion.  See duplicate on how to do two criteria lookups.

Comment: @ScottCraner used the helper column method with index-match and it worked great, thanks!

Comment: Why? use the FILTER method:  `=@FILTER($D:$D,($B:$B=$F2)*($C:$C=G$1))`

Comment: or the SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS($D:$D,$B:$B,$F2,$C:$C,G$1)`